# How to rename SharePoint document and create a new version if the specified file name is already in use?

Tags: sharepoint, version, file-rename, event-receiver

I need to rename an uploaded document by adding some additional information to its file name, currently I do this with an Event Receiver `ItemAdded` wiring up on Document Library, using code

```
    SPListItem material = properties.ListItem;
    material["Name"] = RenameFile(material["Name"].ToString());
    material.Update(); 
    //material.UpdateOverwriteVersion(); //same issue
```

This would works fine until the same file is uploaded again, after renaming the error `"the specified name is already in use"` will occur although I have enabled document version control.

Do I need to create a new version programmatically? if so, how am I supposed to do it, can someone shed some lights on this? Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some help

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1f003923-dc88-427b-a6b8-34c3616d5b1a/

I think you need to check the document out and then back in